# How do you clone, update & append a variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, clone, appendchild

I'm trying to create a variable with the value within '.comments' then prepend the word 'Read all' in front of '4 comments'. Finally, append the new variable to '#comments'.

Manage to write something but it's moving the existing object instead of creating a new object with the value of the existing one.

Some code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var commentsLink = document.querySelector('.story .comments a'),    
    commentsSubmit = document.querySelector('#comments .form-item-submit');
commentsLink.innerHTML = 'Read all ' + commentsLink.innerHTML;
commentsLink.className += 'readComments';
commentsSubmit.appendChild(commentsLink);
</script>

<div class="story">
     <div class="comments">
           <a href="http://foo.com">4 comments</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="comments">
     <div class="form-item-submit">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="story">
     <div class="comments">
           <a href="http://foo.com">4 comments</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="comments">
     <div class="form-item-submit">Submit</div>
     <a href="http://foo.com" class="readComments">Read all 4 comments</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? No Jquery please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To clone elements, use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode). To copy the text contents as well, use `cloneNode(true)`.
2. You want the cloned link to be appended at the *parent* element of the submit `div`, not inside the submit `div` itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/eDGwj/

```
var commentsLink = document.querySelector('.story .comments a').cloneNode(true),
    commentsSubmit = document.querySelector('#comments .form-item-submit');

commentsLink.innerHTML = 'Read all ' + commentsLink.innerHTML;
commentsLink.className += 'readComments';

commentsSubmit.parentNode.appendChild(commentsLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var commentsLink = document.querySelector('.story .comments a'),    
    commentsSubmit = document.querySelector('#comments .form-item-submit'),
    anchor = commentsLink.cloneNode(false);

anchor.innerHTML = 'Read all ' + commentsLink.innerHTML;
anchor.className += ' readComments';

commentsSubmit.parentNode.appendChild(anchor);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, if not please comment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var commentsLink = document.querySelector('.story .comments a'),    
        commentsSubmit = document.querySelector('#comments .form-item-submit');
    var cloneLink = commentsLink.cloneNode(true);
    cloneLink.innerHTML = 'Read all ' + commentsLink.innerHTML;
    cloneLink.className += 'readComments';
    commentsSubmit.appendChild(cloneLink);
</script>
```

The key function was cloneNode(), watch out with the Id's

[More Info](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml)

Hope this helps